# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. How to solve it in Linear Regression?

Tags: sklearn-pandas, train-test-split

I don't understand why this error has occurred. I am doing exactly what my instructor is doing like. Please give me some solution or told me where is the mistake. Thank you.[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvELV.png)

Comment: Code should not be shared as images but as well-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

try this, and search more

```
xtarin.reshape(-1,1)
```